# Insert into sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with the following schema:

```
tblStudent(id NEW ID(),Characteristics nvarchar(max))
```

I want to insert this json object in tblStudents.Characteristics column using normal insert into query.

```
{
    "name": "Debashish Saha",
    "Skills": [{
        "Domain": "cse",
         "interest": "Data Structure"
    }, {
        "Domain": "Language",
        "interest": "English"
    }, {
        "Domain": "Science",
        "interest": "Maths"
    }]
}
```

is my json object.

Is this possible!!

Comment: Be careful here. It looks like your table has a guid as primary key. This carries some baggage with it that you need to understand. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple insert statement. Being JSON doesn't change the syntax:

```
insert into tblStudent (Characteristics)
values
('{ "name": "Debashish Saha", "Skills": [{ "Domain": "cse", "interest": "Data Structure" }, { "Domain": "Language", "interest": "English" }, { "Domain": "Science", "interest": "Maths" }] }');
```